# Github pages not updating

Tags: github, publish

I cannot for the life of me get my published github site to reflect changes in the repo. I've made changes directly from github, pushed a new branch identical to main and set the source to the new branch, and probably attempted other solutions but it won't update from an old commit online. Please help! Thank you!

Online link: https://mgkdn9.github.io/PokeClone
Github repo: https://github.com/mgkdn9/PokeClone

Answer (score 0):

Both the build job and the deploy failed. The github pages [build job log](https://github.com/mgkdn9/PokeClone/runs/4993998961?check_suite_focus=true) contains:

> Fetching submodules
> /usr/bin/git submodule sync --recursive
> /usr/bin/git -c protocol.version=2 submodule update --init --force --depth=1 -- recursive
>
> Error: fatal: No url found for submodule path 'Project-1-Assessment' in .gitmodules
> Error: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128

The log and the messages inside are pretty helpful. It seems you messed up some submodules. The build is working again for an hour or so (after you [have removed the Project1Assessment folder](https://github.com/mgkdn9/PokeClone/commit/b52813e36ec8bdc2bd0380e326b972b94f18e6af)).

Maybe those links were helpful:

- [no-url-found-for-submodule-path-in-gitmodules-error-in-azure-devops-build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59508121/no-url-found-for-submodule-path-in-gitmodules-error-in-azure-devops-build)
- [github-build-and-deploy-error-no-uploaded-artifact-was-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70568350/github-build-and-deploy-error-no-uploaded-artifact-was-found)